# what is the average time between the fist and the last transaction for all customers (average life time - CUMULATIVE)

Tags: sql, group-by, average, aggregate-functions

I was able to compute the time between first and last transaction for every customer (see code below).

```
SELECT customer_id, max(order_time) - min(order_time) as days_from_first_to_last_order,
 (case when count(*) > 1
             then datediff(day, min(order_time), max(order_time)) / (count(*) - 1)
        end) as avg_time
FROM ORDERS
group by customer_id
```

How can I extend this to answer the question  : what is the average time between the fist and last transaction for my customers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add one level of aggregation:

```
SELECT AVG(avg_time) avg_time
FROM (
    SELECT 
        CASE 
            WHEN COUNT(*) > 1 
            THEN datediff(day, min(order_time), max(order_time)) / (count() - 1) 
        END as avg_time 
    FROM orders
    GROUP BY customer_id
) t
```

Note:

- you only need column `avg_time` in the subquery to get the expected result so I removed the others; this means less aggregation computation for your RDBMS
- parentheses around the `case` expression are superfluous

Comment: how can I take in account the return orders in this expression? sometimes I have customers that made one order and one return, and I do not want to count them as two time purchaser @GMB

Answer (score 1):

You can use a second level of aggregation:

```
SELECT AVG(avg_time * 1.0)
FROM (SELECT customer_id, max(order_time) - min(order_time) as days_from_first_to_last_order, (case when count() > 1 then 
             datediff(day, min(order_time), max(order_time)) / nullif(count() - 1, 0)  as avg_time
      FROM ORDERS
      GROUP BY customer_id
     ) c
```

You will notice that I simplified the subquery by using `nullif()`.

Comment: how can I take in account the return orders in this expression? sometimes I have customers that made one order and one return, and I do not want to count them as two time purchaser @GordonLinoff